# why document.execCommand('copy') doesnt copy here?

Tags: javascript

There is a list that when i search colors it opens, i want to copy the color name when i click on the list item, the color name is in a input[type=hidden] but i cant copy the value of the input. execCommand('copy') works fine with input[type=hidden].

link to codepen but you will not get the list because i used ajax for getting colors.
sorry if code is messy, i'm learning!

[codepen](https://codepen.io/Treebeard/pen/bGqqyXG)

```
    function copy(event) {
    var alertColorBox = document.querySelector('.alertCopy .color');
    alertColorBox.style.backgroundColor = event.target.style.backgroundColor;
    var alert = document.querySelector('.alertCopy');
    alert.classList.remove('alertAnimation');
    var alert_span = document.querySelector('.alertCopy span');
    // my question code part
    var input = event.target.querySelector('input');
    input.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    // my question code part
    alert_span.innerHTML = input.value;
    alert.classList.add('alertAnimation');
    setTimeout(removeAlert, 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was with the same problem some time ago. Your code probably will work on Firefox, but on Chromium not.

What I have to do is remove the type="hidden" of the inputs, the I gave then a position="absolute" and "top: -1000px";

This isn't the best way to do that, but works. The inputs will not be visible anymore (on the screen), but the browser will copy the content.

I made this class to simplify:

```
.inputToHide {
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1000px;
}
```

Ps.: Try to indent your code to be easier to understand

==========================================================
EDIT

If you can control your HTML, set a data-color in your div with contain the name of the color, then in the function you just need to create a input, append in the body then copy the content, something like this:

```
var colorInput = document.createElement('input');
colorInput = colorName.getAttribute('data-color');
                
document.body.appendChild(colorInput);
colorInput.select();
document.execCommand("copy");

document.body.removeChild(colorInput);
```

This is a better option after all